# Regression controlling for the influence of group

Tags: r, regression, interaction

My goal is to check whether reading measures are predicted by audiovisual measures, beyond some reading-related measures. So, for example, I have a reading accuracy measure and I want to see whether that is predicted by speech-reading and motion-coherecence detection (all numeric variables), after accounting for the weight of phonological awareness.

For that, I'm running these two models (in R):

```
fitReading <- lm(R_Atotal ~ PAtotal, data=p1)
fitReading1 <- lm(R_Atotal ~ PAtotal + SR + MCD, data = p1)
```

I have two groups in my sample: good readers and poor readers. And I would like to see whether being part of one or the other group has any influence on the models. I guess that, if it does, I should do the regressions separately by group, right?

What is the most correct way to incorporate that interaction in my models?